# Netty Encoding decoding error

Tags: java, maven, netty

I am coding a simple netty packet service. Currently I got a server and a client with a central protocol module.

My Client log looks like this:

PacketId encoded: 1 
Writed packet.
Writing int: 441

My Server log:

PacketId: 8
protocol is null ? with id: 8
PacketId: 1
receiving test with id :0

Encoder:

```
@Override
    protected void encode( ChannelHandlerContext channelHandlerContext, Packet packet, ByteBuf byteBuf ) {
        final Protocol protocol = Protocol.getProtocol( packet.getClass() );

        if ( protocol == null ) {
            throw new IllegalStateException( "The requested packet is not registered!" );
        } else {
            final int packetId = protocol.getId();

            if ( packetId > -1 ) {
                byteBuf.writeInt( packetId );
                System.out.println( "PacketId encoded: " + packetId );
                packet.write( byteBuf );
                System.out.println( "Writed packet." );
            }
        }
    }
```

Decoder:

```
@Override
    protected void decode( ChannelHandlerContext channelHandlerContext, ByteBuf byteBuf, List<Object> list ) throws Exception {
        final int packetId = byteBuf.readInt();
        System.out.println( "PacketId: " + packetId );
        final Protocol protocol = Protocol.getProtocol( packetId );

        if ( protocol == null ) {
            System.out.println( "protocol is null ? with id: " + packetId );
        } else {
            final Class<? extends Packet> packetClass = Objects.requireNonNull( protocol ).getPacketClass();

            if ( packetClass != null ) {
                Packet packet = packetClass.newInstance();
                packet.read( byteBuf );

                list.add( packet );
            }
        }
    }
```

Has somebody an idea on how to solve?

Thanks for any contribution!

Comment: code is not complete, for example what is Protocol?

Comment: Here it is: https://hastebin.com/sobifogosa.java